# Deploying to Azure VM with TeamCity

Tags: git, azure, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I have a Visual Studio solution for a web application that I can Publish from within Visual Studio to my Azure VM. I've setup TeamCity with 2 build steps.

Step 1 - build solution from GIT repo

[image]

Step 2 deploy using MSBUILD.

[image]

The problem I have is that no files are being copied over to the Azure VM. I've copied these build steps from another project in TeamCity but that is deploying to a Amazon VM without problem. Any ideas where to start looking ??

Comment: Are the Azure Publishing Settings checked into the Version Control System. You'd be looking for a .pubxml in the Project/Properties/PublishProperties directory. I would also have expected the Target of the second step to be Publish, rather than rebuild

Comment: I have a profile called Release all checked in. I've just tried changing from Rebuild > Publish, but still no difference.

Comment: I notice that you have the Octopack Plugin installed in your TeamCity instance. Have you attempted to publish to Azure from Ocotpus (you need to install support for it on the tentacle) - I've done this before and there's a great post on the blog - https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/deploy-aspnet-applications-to-azure-websites. I can have a play publishing from TeamCity and let you know what I find.

Comment: Can you edit the post with all the command line parameters you're using in the second step?

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good walkthrough on how to set this up for Azure on the TeamCity documentation site.

I think you might be missing a build configuration here, to do the publishing out to Azure using MSDeploy. The step you've shown should be producing the package ready for publishing. Your build server will require MSDeploy to be installed.

IMHO I would do this through Octopus if you have access to a server (assumed as I saw you had the plugin installed on TeamCity) and are deploying other applications this way too - You then ensure that your build server is unaware of your deployment environments so it has a single responsibility.

[TeamCity - Deploying to Azure](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Continuous+Delivery+to+Windows+Azure+Web+Sites+%28or+IIS%29)

[Octopus - Deploying to Azure](https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/deploy-aspnet-applications-to-azure-websites)

Hope you manage to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll try those when I have a spare minute :)